# return mongodb records that match parent object and sub-document fields

Tags: mongodb, nosql

Having problem of a mongodb query returning to many documents with condition on parent object field and sub-document field. Have two records and this query should only be returning one of them. Basically only return entire document if Type is 'confirmed' and at least one Alerts sub-document has Frequency.Type 'daily' and IsActive is true.

```
db.user.find({$and: [{Type:'confirmed'}, {"Alerts.Frequency.Type":'daily'}, {"Alerts.IsActive":true}]})
```

These are the mongodb records being queried

```
{
    "Email" : "sung@domain.com",
    "Type" : "confirmed",
    "FName" : "Sung",
    "Alerts" : [ 
        {
            "Keyword" : "sales",
            "Frequency" : {
                "Type" : "daily"
            }
            "IsActive" : true
        }
    ]
}

{
    "Email" : "sung2@domain.com",
    "Type" : "confirmed",
    "FName" : "Sung2",
    "Alerts" : [ 
        {
            "Keyword" : "administrative",
            "Frequency" : {
                "Type" : "weekly"
            }
            "IsActive" : true
        },
        {
            "Keyword" : "marketing",
            "Frequency" : {
                "Type" : "daily"
            }
            "IsActive" : false
        }
    ]
}
```

It appears that it is treating {"Alerts.Frequency.Type":'daily'}, {"Alerts.IsActive":true} part of query as an or. If any alert has Type 'daily' or IsActive is true. I need this to be an and. I want the query to just return the first document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ivan's solution will work.  Or you could omit the $and operator to make it even simpler:

```
db.user.find(
    {Type:"confirmed", 
     Alerts:{$elemMatch:{"Frequency.Type":"daily","IsActive":true}}
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use [elemMatch](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/) operator:

```
db.user.find(
{ $and: 
    [
        { Type: 'local' },
        { Alerts: { $elemMatch: { 'Frequency.Type': 'daily', 'IsActive': true } }}
    ]
}
)
```

Your query has returned 2 documents because of in the second document the first element of Alerts array have `"IsActive": true` and the second element of Alerts array have `"Frequency.Type": 'daily'`. If you want to find document where element in Alerts array have both of this conditions (and not find documents where only one condition is truth for one element and another is truth for another element) - you should use `$elemMatch`.